# Xamarin ListView ItemsSource cannot bind data inside PopupPage

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, mvvm, binding-context

I'm stuck with a strange issue.
(In this code, I'm using a [InputKit.Checkbox](https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit))

Followed by [this tutorial](https://almirvuk.blogspot.com/2017/02/xamarinforms-listview-simple-mvvm.html), I've created view, model, and viewmodel like so:

view.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Plugin.InputKit.Shared.Controls;assembly=Plugin.InputKit"
             x:Class="ISSO_I.PopupTypes.MultiselectListView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView RowHeight="70" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <controls:CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" LabelPosition="After" Margin="10"
                                                   Type="Material" Text="{Binding Body}" TextColor="Black" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <BoxView Color="Accent" HeightRequest="1" />
            <controls:CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=AllChecked}" LabelPosition="After" Margin="10" Type="Material"
                               Text="(Выбрать все)" TextColor="Black" />
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStandard}" Margin="10" Text="Применить" Clicked="ButtonConfirmClicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

view.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class MultiselectListView
    {

        private readonly MultiselectListViewModel _vm;

        public event EventHandler ApplyConstrs;

        /// <summary>
        /// Для заголовка окна
        /// </summary>
        public const string Header = "Выбранные номера конструкций";

        public MultiselectListView (ObservableCollection<MultiselectItem> items)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //MultiListView.ItemsSource = _vm.Items;
            BindingContext = _vm = new MultiselectListViewModel(items);
        }

        protected virtual void OnApplyConstrs()
        {
            ApplyConstrs?.Invoke(_vm.Items.Where(item => item.IsChecked).ToList(), EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private async void ButtonConfirmClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnApplyConstrs();
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }
```

view_model.cs:

```cs
public class MultiselectListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Номера конструкций
        /// </summary>
        private ObservableCollection<MultiselectItem> _items;
        public ObservableCollection<MultiselectItem> Items
        {
            get => _items;
            set
            {
                if (_items == value) return;
                _items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
            }
        }

        private bool _allChecked;
        public bool AllChecked
        {
            get => _allChecked;
            set
            {
                if (_allChecked == value) return;
                _allChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AllChecked));
                // Меняем все галочки
                foreach (var item in Items)
                {
                    item.IsChecked = _allChecked;
                }
            }
        }

        public MultiselectListViewModel(ObservableCollection<MultiselectItem> items)
        {
            Items = items;
        }

        #region INotify Staff

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

and finally model.cs:

```cs
public class MultiselectItem
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Признак выбранного элемента
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Текст элемента
        /// </summary>
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

When I use this code, the content in listView not showing at all. But when I aplly ItemsSource in c# code like: `MultiListView.ItemsSource = _vm.Items;` (commited in code), the data appears. I want to do that correctly, by using xaml.

Also, it's strange, but field `AllChecked` never firing in model.

So what is wrong with my code? Could anyone explain me that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SushiHangover perhaps I misunderstand you, but do you mean I have to delete private _items and use only my public `public ObservableCollection<MultiselectItem> Items { get; set; }` ?

Comment: @SushiHangover but `Items` is already public.

Comment: @SushiHangover nope, that didn't help(

Comment: @SushiHangover if it would be interesting for you: I've changed the type of page where the content appears, from `PopupPage` to default `ContentPage`, and everything works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I've found very strange result:

I use a common `PopupPage` with empty `ContentView` in it for initializing many popup pages in two lines of code and not to copy/paste xaml code for initializing it. When I use this class with ListView and my `MultiselectListView` as popup content, the binding doesn't work.

But when I created `PopupPage` 'from zero', binding worked, `ItemsSource` has appeared. It's really strange, but it worked.